# Using TeamCity with BitBucket

Tags: git, teamcity, bitbucket

I am currently setting up a TeamCity build server that will pull source code from our git repositories, which are hosting on Bitbucket.  I am doing this for a repositories that are setup as part of a team on Bitbucket (not my personal account).

What I am running into is that the URL paths seem to be custom for each user.  For example, my paths look like:

```
https://MyUserName@bitbucket.org/TeamName/RepoName.git
```

If I were to leave the company, this would be a nightmare to update for 40+ builds.

I have considered creating a service account on bitbucket for the build server to use, but this will take up one of our users (we only have a 10-user license).

Is creating a separate account the recommended approach, or are there better options?

Comment: If your build doesn't require making changes to the repo, does bitbucket allow anonymous, read-only access, without an account? If so, then you could just use `git clone git://hostname/TeamName/RepoName.git` -- that is how I have set up TeamCity in the past.

Comment: @ShaggyFrog: Presumably only if it's a *public* repo, which I'm guessing this isn't.

Comment: It is indeed a private repo.

Comment: What version of TeamCity?

Comment: The latest version, I believe 8.0.4.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should use a deployment key. It gives read-only access to both private and public repositories. Check the documentation at https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Use+deployment+keys

Comment: The deployment keys are good but unfortunately the build server can't label the repo after a build.

Comment: Same problem here, they don't allow buid tagging or checking in of a log file.

Answer (score 1):

Creating a separate account is an acceptable approach if you want to do more on TeamCity side than just pull code for builds (for example, labeling builds, etc.). If you use a separate account for your TeamCity you could use both user/password authentication or SSH key authentication.

In the repository URL path you can safely remove the "MyUserName@" part which would make all the repository URLs uniformed regardless of how you access them. Moreover you could parameterize the user name and password in the TeamCity configuration so they can be overridden when someone wants to run a custom build.

As far as I am concerned there is no "recommended approach" for TeamCity since TeamCity is Git flavor agnostic. But Atlassian suggests to use SSH key when integrating with Bamboo. I am using a dedicated account for as long as I have one in the license since it makes management and debugging much easier.

Comment: Unfortunately you can't parameterise the password (I'm using 2017.1)